# Inconsistent result sets from MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Not sure how to remove this, but this has been solved.  Thanks!**

**EDIT: as requested, full stored proc code is at the bottom**

I'm getting a very odd issue with inconsistent result sets from mysql in this stored procedure that I'm writing.  I've included the debug statements I'm using and their outputs:

Statements (these are all on consecutive lines / appear in code exactly as written):

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM event_task';
SELECT * from event_task;
SELECT 'SELECT event_id FROM event_task';
SELECT event_id FROM event_task;
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM event_task WHERE event_id = 1';
SELECT * FROM event_task WHERE event_id = 1;
SELECT 'end select';
```

The result I get is:

```
mysql> call get_user_events(1);
+--------------------------+
| SELECT * FROM event_task |
+--------------------------+
| SELECT * FROM event_task |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+----+----------+---------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | event_id | user_id | task   | complete | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------+---------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 | stuff  |        0 | 2012-08-30 00:00:00 | 2012-08-30 00:00:00 |
|  2 |        1 |       2 | stuff2 |        1 | 2012-08-30 00:00:00 | 2012-08-30 00:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+---------------------------------+
| SELECT event_id FROM event_task |
+---------------------------------+
| SELECT event_id FROM event_task |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+----------+
| event_id |
+----------+
|     NULL |
|     NULL |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| SELECT * FROM event_task WHERE event_id = 1 |
+---------------------------------------------+
| SELECT * FROM event_task WHERE event_id = 1 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Empty set (0.01 sec)

+------------+
| end select |
+------------+
| end select |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Basically, even though I can see that the event_ids are 1 when I do select * from event_task, when I re-query event_task for event_id as a specific column I get NULL values.

edit: just selected out the user ID with the following:

```
SELECT 'SELECT user_id';
SELECT user_id;
```

The result is:

```
mysql> call get_user_events(1);
+----------------+
| SELECT user_id |
+----------------+
| SELECT user_id |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

AS REQUESTED: FULL STORED PROC CODE

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_user_events$$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_user_events (IN user_id int) 
/*
gets the user's events for the default page
grabs: image location, event title, date, location, number of tasks completed / total, and updates
*/
BEGIN
    DECLARE done TINYINT(1) DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE loop_cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE event_id INT;

    DECLARE update_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM aggregate;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET done = TRUE;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tasks;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS aggregate;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS updates;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tasks (id int, event_id int, complete tinyint(1));
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE aggregate (id int, picture_location varchar(255), name varchar(255), date timestamp, 
        place varchar(255), num_tasks int, tasks_complete int, status_update varchar(5000));
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE updates (event_id int, status_update varchar(255));

    /*get basic event information*/
    INSERT INTO aggregate (id, picture_location, name, date, place)
    SELECT e.id,
           e.picture_location, 
           e.name, 
           ed.date,
           ep.place
    FROM event e INNER JOIN event_user_map eum ON e.id = eum.event_id
                 LEFT JOIN event_place ep ON e.id = ep.event_id AND ep.vote_final = 1
                 LEFT JOIN event_date ed ON e.id = ed.event_id AND ed.vote_final = 1
    WHERE eum.user_id = user_id;

    /*grab the list of tasks so we can work with a small subset*/
    INSERT INTO tasks 
        SELECT id, event_id, complete 
        FROM event_task 
        WHERE event_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM aggregate);

    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM event_task';
    SELECT * from event_task;
    SELECT 'SELECT event_id FROM event_task';
    SELECT event_id FROM event_task;
    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM event_task WHERE event_id = 1';
    SELECT * FROM event_task WHERE event_id = 1;
    SELECT 'SELECT event_id FROM (SELECT * FROM event_task) as A';
    SELECT event_id FROM (SELECT * FROM event_task) as A;
    SELECT 'end select';

    /*gets tasks*/
    UPDATE aggregate SET num_tasks = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE event_id = id);
    UPDATE aggregate SET tasks_complete = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE event_id = id AND complete = 1);

    /*get updates*/
    OPEN update_cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH update_cur INTO event_id;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO updates
            SELECT event_id, status_update FROM event_update ORDER BY updated_at limit 3;
    END LOOP;

    UPDATE aggregate SET status_update = (SELECT group_concat(status_update) FROM updates u WHERE u.event_id = id);

    SELECT * FROM aggregate;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: event_task is defined how? Can you LOCK the table during the procedure tests?

Comment: event task is defined with:
id int, event_id int, user_id int, task varchar(255), complete tinyint(1), created_at datetime, updated_at datetime

event_id and user_id are both foreign keys.  When I run the query select event_id from event_task just in mysql through commandline, it returns the correct answer, but when the statement is in a stored proc, it seems to break.

*edit: just tried locking the table with SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; around those select statements - no change.  Also tried Read Uncommtted - no luck.

Comment: In these terms, it just *can't be*. There must be something else going on... can you post the whole stored procedure? -- EDIT: maybe I got it. Can you select, as debug, in the stored procedure, *the ID you're passing as function argument*?

Comment: I can, but I don't end up using that id in any of the debug statements which is why I ruled that part out.  

However, as you asked, I commented out the other debugs - I'll edit the main question to post the results.  If this doesn't work I can post the proc.  Maybe it's something I'm missing about MySQL, as I'm much more familiar with t-SQL

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you `SELECT event_id FROM (SELECT *  FROM event_task) a`?

Comment: Interesting idea - just did it and I'm still getting NULLs.  I used the following query in my proc:

SELECT event_id FROM (SELECT * FROM event_task) as A;

(sorry I would include the result set but formatting in comments isn't treating me so well.  I get the column 'event_id', and 2 null rows though (same as without the subquery).

Comment: can you post your full Stored Procedure code?

Comment: you have variable event_id declared, it might be causing issue.

Comment: can you change your `DECLARE event_id INT;`  to `DECLARE event_id_var INT;` and run your stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Posting my comment as answer:

Change your `DECLARE event_id INT;` to `DECLARE event_id_var INT;` and run your stored procedure